# Subfigure environment puts figures top and bottom, instead of side by side

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

This question was asked, but I don't seem to resolve my case by adapting solutions from others.

I am simply trying to put two figures side by side. However, regardless of the linewidth setting, my figures constantly placed top and bottom. My code is very simple.

```
\begin{figure}[h!]

\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{pic1caption}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}{.5\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{pic2.jpg}
    \caption{pic2caption.jpg}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Figure caption}

\end{figure}
```

Any help / pointer would be appreciated!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Well, you're using `\caption` in each subfigure instead of the option of the command `\subfigure[caption]` where you should add each subcaption, and the `\caption` is for the set of subfigures. Take a look that `\subfigure` is a command or macro, bot an environment. Maybe you're confused with the usage of the `subfig` packages that replaces the `subfigure` one that is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Omit the space between the two *subfigures* putting a `%` symbol after of the first `\end{subfigure}` (i.e `\end{subfigure}%`).
- Reduce the width of the *subfigures* for example to `0.45\linewidth`, (i.e. `\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}`). This allows to keep the space between both subfigures without forcing a change of line.

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{caption,subcaption}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{pic1.jpg}
      \caption{pic1caption}
  \end{subfigure} 
  \begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
      \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{pic2.jpg}
      \caption{pic2caption.jpg}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The first choice did the trick. If I may ask one more: In my initial snippet, I had extra line, between two subfigures. They did affect formatting, I think. In general, in Latex, should I avoid them?

Comment: Of course, an extra line means a change of paragraph, it is equivalent to `\par`. So the figures will be showed in different line.

Comment: Ah, thanks for your kind comments. Much appreciated!