# How can I customise the code for side-by-side subfigures so they can be adjusted up or down?

Tags: subfloats

How can you move a subfigure up and down arbitrarily when using the code written [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207220/subfigure-environment-puts-figures-top-and-bottom-instead-of-side-by-side) ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{pic1.jpg}
    \caption{pic1caption}
\end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{pic2.jpg}
    \caption{pic2caption.jpg}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added the code from that answer.

Comment: I tried using '\vspace{}'. Works as well after many trials, but this here seems to be much more appropriate! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `raisebox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{pic1caption}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \raisebox{0.5\height}{\includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{pic2caption.jpg}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have use `[b]` to keep the sub captions at the same level.

[image]

Or use `adjustbox`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{pic1caption}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.45\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[draft,width=\linewidth,raise=2ex]{example-image-a}
    \caption{pic2caption.jpg}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that there is also `valign` key with `adjustbox` if it boils down to aligning figures.